# Issue with the checkboxes in primeng

Tags: primeng

I have serious issue, I searched for hours but no solution find
Big thanks for help

Issue is

I am using PrimeNg components.
I have a check box in data table and another check box out side the `datatable` when I am clicking the `checkbox` out side the `datatable` the `checkbox` is checked in `datatable` but when I uncheck the checkbox of outside `datatable` the checkbox is not unchecked in `datatable`

Comment: share your code. not clear!

Comment: ok, i will share in 5 min, thank you

Comment: <p-checkbox binary="true" [(ngModel)] = "confirmAllFlag" (onChange) = "changeConfirmAllFlagMethod($event)"></p-checkbox>

Comment: <p-dataTable [(value)]="offenderPptyItemsListData" [rows]="5" reorderableColumns="true"
   (onRowClick)="onRowSelectOffenderPptyItems($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" [(selection)]="selectedOffenderPptyItem"
   [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,15]" editable="true" 
   [responsive]="true"  #dt > 
<p-column field="confirmFlag" header="Confirm" >
<ng-template let-row="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" let-col pTemplate type="body" >
 <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" [binary]="true"></p-checkbox>
 </ng-template>
</p-column> 
</p-dataTable>

Comment: @santhosh, please don't put code in comments. It is very hard to read. Instead, [edit] your question and paste the code there. Then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.